# Как элемент из символьного массива сделать целым числом и записать в переменную целого типа?

Tags: c

Нужно ли для этого пользоваться atoi , просто у меня ничего подобного не получилось , выводится ноль

```
char num1[80];
printf("Enter: ");
gets(num1);
printf("%d", atoi(num1));
return 0;
```

Comment: Что-то вы недоговариваете: https://ideone.com/FHbSrt - как видите, работает...

Comment: @Harry,но я хочу ввести ,например, ААА и получить 656565

Answer (score 1):

*я хочу ввести ,например, ААА и получить 656565*

Тогда делайте что-то вроде

```
for(char * с = num1; *c; ++c)
    printf("%02d",*c);
```

См. https://ideone.com/ggtnkV

Comment: ,а почему *с , что это значит здесь?

Comment: Символ, на который указывает указатель `c`. Просто в цикле проходим по всем символам введенной строки.

Answer (score 0):

До меня тоже дошло

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char num1[80];
    int A[80];
    int j = 0;
    printf("Enter: ");
    gets_s(num1);
    int i = 0;
    while (num1[i] != '\0') 
    {
        A[i]=int(num1[i++]);

    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", A[j]);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```